# package.json block a dependencies dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I am using the `semantic-ui-css` package.
In my app I then import a css file from that package:

```
import './../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
```

That CSS file is **all** I want from the package.

Unfortunatley that library is not css only, it includes all the JS required for the semantic-ui, to do transitions and similar UI effects. As such it has a dependency of `jquery`.

I don't want that 100kb in my project.

I know my project doesn't need the parts of the `semantic-ui-css` package that require `jquery`, so my question is can I somehow specify in my package file not to install that dependency (jquery)?

I am using yarn by the way.
I had a rough look at [selective version resolution](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) in yarn. But that seems to be about locking dependencies to a version - not avoiding dependencies.

Similarly, I don't want to add all the files I do need as raw assets to my repo, I want to keep using a package manager if possible.

Comment: Why do you care? Those JS files will not be included in your final build; they are just in `node_modules`...

Comment: @ThiefMaster it started with me getting a vulnerability alert for jquery, and then I just got curious as to whether it is possible. In this case it isn't critical, because it's a small dep (100kb), but in other cases I might want to reduce the packages downloaded. I also like the idea of having a cleaner dependency graph.